# Same project can be compiled successfully with xcode 11.7, but fails with xcode 12.1

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation

Error occurs while compiling with xcode 12.1. Full descriptionns are as follows:

```
ld: in
/Volumes/E/AppDev/Project/iOS/platforms/ios/sdk/libHiP2PSDK.a(HIPPP4Compatible_API.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '/Volumes/E/AppDev/Project/iOS/platforms/ios/sdk/libHiP2PSDK.a' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried many other possible solutions found for this related error but still won't work. Hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a whole mountain of problems with the new xcode version, this is one of them

Comment: @krumpli Currently I just found this one and don't know how to get it resolved. And I am trying to submit with binary compieled with xcode 11.7.

Comment: I have the same issues as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063385/flutter-app-on-xcode-wont-launch-after-upgrade