# Flutter app on Xcode won't launch after upgrade

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have an app made in Flutter and since the latest version of Xcode absolutely nothing works as before.
I have been struggling with this problem for nearly a week now and the errors vary depending on the hour.

The main problem is that when distributing the application to Apple for review, they reject it with the following message:

---

> 2.1 Performance: App Completeness Guideline
>
> 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
> running iOS 14.0 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, we were still unable to login through Sign in with Apple

---

I find this strange as all my previous uploads got verified without any problems.
So to rectify this issue I'm trying to run the app through the simulator as I don't own an iPad.
And here is where the problems start.

Side note: Running on a physical iPhone works without problems and I'm opening the project `runner.xcworkspace`, not the `runner.xccodeproj`.

The main problem is that Xcode won't find any libraries, starting with the first one:

> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: Module 'apple_sign_in' not found

I have tried every solution related to this issue but to no avail.

- Remove the pod files, pod install,
- pod deintegrate, pod init, pod install
- flutter build ios --release, flutter run
- Ive tried removing my project and cloning it for a fresh start
- Sometimes not even a boilerplate app will work
- I have checked github posts like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53573 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33423 with no luck.
- ...checked countless threads.

Flutter doctor and pod-file below:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021,
> locale en-ES)
> • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /Users/peter/flutter
> • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (11 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
> • Engine revision d1bc06f032
> • Dart version 2.9.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.1)
> • Android SDK at /Users/peter/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
> • Java binary at:
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.0, Build version 12A7209
> • CocoaPods version 1.9.3
>
> [!] Android Studio (not installed)
> • Android Studio not found; download from
> https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
> (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
> for detailed instructions).
>
> [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2.5)
> • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
> ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • For information about installing plugins, see
> https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • iPhone 11 (mobile) • F1B8AE15-9028-4E0D-BD9D-2F2C7CC93ECE • ios •
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is very strange that you are able to execute a Xcode build if it warn you about a missing module. How you implemented Apple SignIn? With a package?

Comment: @E.Benedos I can run the code on a physical device but not on a simulator, thats when the import error occurs. Apple sign in is with a package that i have used for a few months now. Im using this: https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in

Comment: Have you also tried to open an issue on the dedicated repo? It seems a package problem and not a flutter one.

Comment: @E.Benedos. if i remove that package, it will give me the same error for the next package in line. If I can complie and run on a physical device,  there shouldn't be any reason not to be able to do the same on a simulator.

Comment: package wise issues may result if you are using a non-stable flutter release. You would return to the stable channel, then (you can google for this). But the error I received in this situation was different to yours. However, based on the Apple statements I understand  you are lacking the Apple ID login possibility. So from there, I would investigate towards your problem (implemented, package running with flutter release, working package feature...)

Comment: @w461It all worked before iOS14 and the last xcode update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75901008/14167970 This will work 100%, look into this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894992/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-in-xcode-14-3-after-update-flutter-and-xcod/75901008#75901008

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with Flutter 1.20.4 and XCode12/iOS14.
You need to update Flutter to the current beta (1.22.0-12.3.pre) which contains a lot of fixes for the new iOS/XCode versions.

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14

**Edit 10/01/2020:**
Flutter 1.22.0 has been released to stable and should work with XCode 12 and iOS 14 out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the iOS Simulator.

Check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533) forum.

You might want to reply to them pointing out this issue from the forum, seems to have worked for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to allow the module in xcode to see if it finds `apple_sign_in`

Open Xcode select `Runner >  Signing % Capabilities > +Capabilities > Select Apple_Sign_In`

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUJSu.png)

Comment: Yep, that's all there. I haven't touched any of these settings since the last working and accepted version of my app.