# Debut iOS from Flutter

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

I'm start studing Flutter, is excellent, I have create 2 page and on Android is work all, on iOS no because when I debug, after is show:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone di XX in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: B7W38C7R68
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            4,7s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

WHy? Where is the error if on Android work?
I have use alls terminal, don't work :(

Help me

I have a big difficult in don't work debug iOS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing file (libarclite\_iphoneos.a) in Xcode 14.3 after update flutter and xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894992/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-in-xcode-14-3-after-update-flutter-and-xcod)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. I was able to fix this by modifying my `ios/Podfile` by adding those lines within the post_install hook:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The problem seems to be that the deployment target for iOS needs to be set to 11.0 or higher for iOS 16.4 for all build configurations.

See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725300